# java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to run google driver example

Tags: google-oauth, google-drive-api

Hi guys I want to use google drive api to do some task, however I new to Drive API, OAuth2.0 protocol too. Following [this example](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_3_set_up_the_sample)  I end up with this exception which I really don't understand what is happening I copied the example as is copy/past, added my CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and REDIRECT_URI but nothing.

Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
    at com.gpaps.apps.expensesmanager.google.drive.DriverReportExporter.main(DriverReportExporter.java:47)
```

The exception is thrown when I call  `GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();`

I checked every object and everything was Ok.

Thanks for helping me in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Tracing the error through the client library source code, the NPE appears to stem from `response.getContent()` returning null here in [`TokenResponseException.from()`](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/google-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/TokenResponseException.java?name=1.18.0-rc#89). I'm not sure why the response would not have any content, but it's a bug that the client library doesn't detect this state and handle it more appropriately. There is already an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/issues/detail?id=96) on the project's issue tracker to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh thank you, I then should mention the lib version I am using so that people know which lib we are talking about.

Comment: I am getting the same npe for Directory API, when I use directoy.insert.execute(), is there any workaround?